# Managing job in SSMS 19.0.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms, jobs, sql-server-agent

I've created jobs with multiple steps that run a stored procedure for different variables.  For each step, I've set retry attempts to 10 with 1 minute intervals.  I've noticed that even though a step successfully completes the stored procedure, it will still go ahead and retry the step 10 times before going to the next step.  What can I do to stop this from happening, short of removing the retry attempts?  Thank you for your help.

I could remove the retry attempts but want to know what other mitigations I can apply to ensure that the job step doesn't repeat itself despite being successful.

Comment: That isn't how jobs normally work, so something sounds wrong here. I suggest showing us how you set the job and its steps up and the logs from that job.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  I figured it out.  It turned out to be very minor syntax errors in the stored procedure in new code that I had added to the end of it.  I was missing extra ticks around a string.  The job appeared to be successful at first because the output was written to a report before the execution of the new code at the end.